# What's the fastest way to pass an image between two activities?

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso

Say that I have:

`Activity` activity1 containing `ImageView` imageView1

and

`Activity` activity2 containing `ImageView` imageView2,

and I have a string url pointing to an image (cached by `Picasso`), which I already loaded into imageView1.
How can I launch Activitiy2 and load the same image into ImageView2 in the fastest way?

Currently, I'm calling the `Picasso.load().into()` on the url as soon as the activity is launched. This is fast, but I'm looking for something faster.

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
        .load(myUrl)
        .into(imageView2);
```

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picasso downloads the complete image and saves the original image in disk/memory. Suppose the original image dimension was 800x800 and you are trying to load this image into a view with dimension: 100x100, then Picasso will take some time for re-sizing. 
You might want to give Glide[1] a try. Glide has the option to cache both re-sized images and original image as well.  (check Glide#diskCachingStratedgy)

Also,  with Picasso, if you use .noFade() option, then the image might appear to load a bit faster.

[1] https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

Comment: Found out the .noFade() method was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is already fast enough. Picasso just gets it from shared memory cache, where it is stored as ready to use bitmap. It is faster, than using intent.putExtra("image". bitmapByteArray) or using file with decoded or encoded bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create three classes for storing images in cache memory and it is very faster for loading images.
1. ImageLoader.java
2. FileCache.java
3. MemoryCache.java

ImageLoader.java

```
package com.thefinal3.Camera;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.thefinal3.R;
import com.thefinal3.Utils.Utils;

/**
 * Created by Akash patel on 03-05-2016.
 */
public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int stub_id= R.drawable.ic_no_image;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u;
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if(bitmap!=null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

FileCache.java

```
package com.thefinal3.Camera;

import android.content.Context;

import java.io.File;

/**
 * Created by Akash patel on 03-05-2016.
 */
public class FileCache {

    private File cacheDir;

    public FileCache(Context context){
        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"TTImages_cache");
        else
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    public File getFile(String url){
        //I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the demo.
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        //Another possible solution (thanks to grantland)
        //String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        return f;

    }

    public void clear(){
        File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
        if(files==null)
            return;
        for(File f:files)
            f.delete();
    }

}
```

MemoryCache.java

```
    package com.thefinal3.Camera;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Map.Entry;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class MemoryCache {

        private static final String TAG = "MemoryCache";
        private Map<String, Bitmap> cache= Collections.synchronizedMap(
                new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10, 1.5f, true));//Last argument true for LRU ordering
        private long size=0;//current allocated size
        private long limit=1000000;//max memory in bytes

        public MemoryCache(){
            //use 25% of available heap size
            setLimit(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/4);
        }

        public void setLimit(long new_limit){
            limit=new_limit;
            Log.i(TAG, "MemoryCache will use up to " + limit / 1024. / 1024. + "MB");
        }

        public Bitmap get(String id){
            try{
                if(!cache.containsKey(id))
                    return null;
                //NullPointerException sometimes happen here http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=78
                return cache.get(id);
            }catch(NullPointerException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
            try{
                if(cache.containsKey(id))
                    size-=getSizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
                cache.put(id, bitmap);
                size+=getSizeInBytes(bitmap);
                checkSize();
            }catch(Throwable th){
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void checkSize() {
            Log.i(TAG, "cache size="+size+" length="+cache.size());
            if(size>limit){
                Iterator<Entry<String, Bitmap>> iter=cache.entrySet().iterator();//least recently accessed item will be the first one iterated
                while(iter.hasNext()){
                    Entry<String, Bitmap> entry=iter.next();
                    size-=getSizeInBytes(entry.getValue());
                    iter.remove();
                    if(size<=limit)
                        break;
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Clean cache. New size "+cache.size());
            }
        }

        public void clear() {
            try{
                //NullPointerException sometimes happen here http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=78
                cache.clear();
                size=0;
            }catch(NullPointerException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if(bitmap==null)
                return 0;
            return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
        }
    }
```

After creating above three classes you just need load image in imageview like this :

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity);
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(bean.getPhotoURL(),holder.imgSelectedPhoto);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will get an eye on it as soon as possible

Comment: Loading and caching images is a low level operation. Generally speaking, embedding low level code inside an application is extremely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a quantitative measure for "fast"(like 0.1 sec)? You can do it easily with -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

And retrieve it as -

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

Comment: Correct. Problem is that I have a big quantity of photos, and the conversion to bitmap is an expensive process.. I should try to convert onClick but this would probably lose the "speed" I'm looking for.
Currently my loading is taking about 2 secs, I would like to stay under 0.5